# How to set input type date value manually in HTML

Tags: html

I have an input type date like this:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="tglmsk" id="tglmsk" value="2013-01-08">
```

But everytime i open it, the date value doesn't show on the input box, i already try to use this format on the :

> yyyy-mm-dd (2013-01-08)
>
> dd-mm-yyyy (08-01-2013)

But both of them didn't work

Comment: The code sample you've provided with `value="2013-01-08"` works for me. What browser are you using? Are you sure you're editing the correct file/input?

Comment: @Wrokar i am using Google Chrome, yes i am sure because i inspect the input box using Google Chrome inspect tools

Answer (score 1):

The `type="date"` inputs have [partial browser support](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_date.asp). If you're not using IE or Safari, then try localising your HTML with the `lang` attribute. The value preset of *YYYY-MM-DD* is correct and should work.

Keep in mind, if you change the date in the field you won't see it in the DOM inspection. The presentation and the actual submission value should be correct, though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is the value 2013-01-08 not prepopulated in the field?

Comment: sorry, it works now, the problem is not on the input type date, but on my jquery, thanks a lot btw